# Extra Cases in AVL Trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree, tree-rotation

AVL Trees seem to have four kinds of transformations: Left-Left, Left-Right, Right-Left, and Right-Right.  However, it seems like there could be other circumstances as well.  I submit this as Left-Balanced:

[image]

Neither Left nor Right rotations can balance this tree.  What algorithm would one use to balance it?

Comment: AV&L did _not_ give a procedure to balance _any_ ordered binary tree into an AVL tree with "at most one double rotation". They presented how to re-balance a binary tree after an insertion of a single node using but one of three states/two extra bits per node. This was extended to other operations. None of the three "left" trees shown above can be the result of adding a single node to a valid AVL tree, each might result from deleting one node deserving a label greater than 50. That said, what (in terms of height) _is_ different in the nodes labelled 40 and 45 between the "last two left trees"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both LL and LR can be applied here

```
        50
       /  \
     40    55
    /  \
  35    45
  / \   / \
34  36 44 46
```

After first LR turn:

```
           50
          /  \
        45   55
       /  \
     40    46
    /  \
  35    44
  / \
34  36
```

After second LR turn:

```
        45
       /  \
     40    50
    / \    / \
  35  44  46  55
 / \
34  36
```

This is the valid AVL tree.  Note that

> In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node **differ by at most one**

You can also do the LL turn:

```
     40
    /  \
  35    50
  / \   / \
34  36 45  55
       /\
     44  46
```

Again this is the valid AVL tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't get the left-balance case.
Because if you built the left-balance one, you may get the left-left or left-right first, then the tree would rotate and keep balance.

Comment: You get each of the depicted cases deleting a single node from the right sub-tree of a valid AVL tree.